# WP Как дать возможность обычным постам выбирать кастомную рубрику?

Tags: php, wordpress

Подскажите, как постам дать возможность назначать кастомную рубрику. Вот пример кода:

```
/*
 *  Регистрация таксономии производителей
 */

add_action( 'init', 'create_vendor_taxonomies' );

// функция, создающая таксономии "vendors" для постов типа "vendor"
function create_vendor_taxonomies(){

    // Добавляем древовидную таксономию 'vendor' (как категории)
    register_taxonomy('vendors', array('vendor', 'post'), array(
        'hierarchical'  => true,
        'labels'        => array(
            'name'              => _x( 'Vendors', 'taxonomy general name' ),
            'singular_name'     => _x( 'Vendor', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
            'search_items'      =>  __( 'Search Vendors' ),
            'all_items'         => __( 'All Vendors' ),
            'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Vendor' ),
            'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Vendor:' ),
            'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Vendor' ),
            'update_item'       => __( 'Update Vendor' ),
            'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Vendor' ),
            'new_item_name'     => __( 'NewVendor Name' ),
            'menu_name'         => __( 'Vendors' ),
        ),
        'show_ui'       => true,
        'query_var'     => true,
        //'rewrite'       => array( 'slug' => 'the_genre' ), // свой слаг в URL
    ));
}




/*
 *  Тип записей для производителей Тип записи vendor
 */

function create_vendors_posttype() {
    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x( 'Вендоры', 'Тип записей Вендоры', 'bahisyasal' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'Вендор', 'Тип записей вендоры', 'bahisyasal' ),
        'menu_name' => __( 'Вендоры', 'bahisyasal' ),
        'all_items' => __( 'Все производители', 'bahisyasal' ),
        'view_item' => __( 'Обзор производителя', 'bahisyasal' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Добавить нового производителя', 'bahisyasal' ),
        'add_new' => __( 'Добавить нового производителя', 'bahisyasal' ),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Редактировать производителя', 'bahisyasal' ),
        'update_item' => __( 'Обновить произаодителя', 'bahisyasal' ),
        'search_items' => __( 'Искать производителя', 'bahisyasal' ),
        'not_found' => __( 'Не найдено', 'bahisyasal' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'Не найдено в корзине', 'bahisyasal' ),
    );

    $args = array(
        'label' => __( 'vendor', 'bahisyasal' ),
        'description' => __( 'Каталог производителей', 'bahisyasal' ),
        'labels' => $labels,
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'revisions', 'custom-fields', ),
        'taxonomies' => array( 'category', 'vendors' ),
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar' => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'can_export' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-groups',
        'capability_type' => 'page',
    );

    register_post_type( 'vendors', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_vendors_posttype', 0 );
```

Подскажите как для обычных постов сделать связь с постами типа vendor из таксономии vendors ?
Что то по типу Меток. Только что б для Производителей ?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте в аргументы функции `register_taxonomy` параметр `show_in_rest` для того что бы отображать таксономию в гутенберге

```
register_taxonomy('vendors', array('vendors', 'post'), array(
    'hierarchical'  => true,
    'labels'        => array(
        'name'              => _x( 'Vendors', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name'     => _x( 'Vendor', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'search_items'      =>  __( 'Search Vendors' ),
        'all_items'         => __( 'All Vendors' ),
        'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Vendor' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Vendor:' ),
        'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Vendor' ),
        'update_item'       => __( 'Update Vendor' ),
        'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Vendor' ),
        'new_item_name'     => __( 'NewVendor Name' ),
        'menu_name'         => __( 'Vendors' ),
    ),
    'show_ui'       => true,
    'show_in_rest' => true,
    'query_var'     => true,
    //'rewrite'       => array( 'slug' => 'the_genre' ), // свой слаг в URL
));
```

Comment: Спасибо,  это помогло, а можно ещё объяснить как кастомная рубрика связывается с кастомным типом записи ? Есть ли вообще эта связь ?  Просто wp показал мне страницу /vendors/  (которую я задал в archive-vendors.php) а  вот на страницу /vendors/example/ выдает ошибку не пойму какой шаблон за неё отвечает. single-vendors.php отображает кастомный тип записи...

Comment: для этого можно создать шаблон taxonomy-vendors.php